# On Oreo, setColorFilter() on a SeekBar thumb changes all thumbs

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, seekbar-thumb

I have a class `public class LevelSeekBar extends AppCompatSeekBar`.  Within that class, I have this method:

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    int color = getResources().getColor(getColorForState(enabled));
    getThumb().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

This LevelSeekBar is used within a custom list, implemented using a RecyclerView.  On a refresh, each LevelSeekBar.setEnabled() is called one after the other.

On devices < Android 8.0 (Oreo), this works completely as expected.

However, on Android 8.0, **all** of the Thumbs are set based on the last color set in the list.  In other words, let's say I have a list of 2 items -- the first one is 'disabled' and the second one is 'enabled' -- both items will show up as enabled.

I have confirmed in the debugger that the 'enabled' variable and the corresponding color returned are correct and as-expected, and I have confirmed that the full recyclerview is being refreshed in this case.

Seems like an Oreo bug.  Has anyone else seen this, or have any ideas for how to work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.mutate()` on the Drawable that is returned by `getThumb()`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()